# Подсчет среднего значение по нескольким полям

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно подсчитать средний бал по каждому товару при том если значение NULL, то его не считать при вычислении средней оценки().
Второй день пытаюсь сообразить - все не то.

Comment: Где конкретно у Вас возникли затруднения? Покажите, что у Вас получилось.

Comment: среднее значение вычисляет функция `AVG()`, ну и группировку по товару (group by) добавьте.

Comment: SELECT id_product, AVG(functionality_rate+quality_rate+design_rate) FROM ps_product_rating_users GROUP BY id_product

Comment: Результат запроса: http://joxi.ru/J2byPwxC4G35ym.jpg

Comment: Мне нужно что бы если среднее значение стоит 2 оценки с трех, то и делить на 2

Comment: `AVG(functionality_rate)+AVG(quality_rate)+AVG(design_rate)`

Comment: точнее даже `COALESCE(AVG(functionality_rate),0)+...` т.е. сначала получаем средние, потом NULL превращаем в 0 и после этого складываем

Comment: Результат не совсем то.. http://joxi.ru/Vm6z8NKcxjy1Dm

Comment: тогда задайте вопрос по человечески. приведите входные данные текстом, а не картинкой и лучше прямо в виде `create table / insert` что бы можно было сделать тестовую БД и пробовать на ней. И главное, приведите на основе этих данных вычисленный руками результат (то же в виде текста), который вы хотите получить.что бы было понятно что такое "средняя оценка". ссылка "править" под текстом вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Среднее по строке:

```
select id_product, (coalesce(functionality_rate,0)+coalesce(quality_rate,0)+coalesce(design_rate,0))/
(coalesce(functionality_rate/functionality_rate,0)+coalesce(quality_rate/quality_rate,0)+coalesce(design_rate/design_rate,0)) avg_ 
from t;
```

Среднее по продукту:

```
select id_product, avg(avg_) from
(select id_product, (coalesce(functionality_rate,0)+coalesce(quality_rate,0)+coalesce(design_rate,0))/
(coalesce(functionality_rate/functionality_rate,0)+coalesce(quality_rate/quality_rate,0)+coalesce(design_rate/design_rate,0)) avg_ 
from t
) X
group by id_product;
```